GitHub Actions: Supabase Postgres container fails to initialize with 'password authentication failed for user supabase_admin
I'm trying to set up a GitHub Actions workflow which would start supabase database as a step , I eventually want to run my tests that i have written in Django , But when trying to start the Supabase Postgres container getting these initialization errors. Here's my current configuration and the error:
Error message:
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/migrate.sh
   [local] 2024-10-31 01:36:07.736 UTC [75] supabase_admin@test_db FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "supabase_admin"
   [local] 2024-10-31 01:36:07.736 UTC [75] supabase_admin@test_db DETAIL:  Role "supabase_admin" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 82: "local all  supabase_admin     scram-sha-256"
  Error: Failed to initialize container supabase/postgres:15.6.1.133
Error: One or more containers failed to start.

Current GitHub Actions workflow configuration:
services:
  postgres:
    image: supabase/postgres:15.6.1.133
    env:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ****
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/test_db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    options: >-
      --health-cmd="pg_isready -U postgres"
      --health-interval=10s
      --health-timeout=5s
      --health-retries=5


Looked into your issue but couldn't pinpoint it to a specific root cause. Apparently, it's something specific to supabase. You might want to open an issue on their repo to get clarification on this.
However, this is what's working for me:
name: supabase_services_container

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      postgres:
        image: supabase/postgres:15.6.1.133
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: test_db
        ports:
        - 5432:5432
        options: >-
          --health-cmd=pg_isready
          --health-interval=10s
          --health-timeout=5s
          --health-retries=5

    steps:
      - name: Install postgresql-client (psql)
        run: |
          sudo apt update -y
          sudo apt install -y postgresql-client
          psql --version

      - name: Check
        run: |
          psql "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432" <<EOF
            CREATE TABLE test (id INT);
            INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (123);
            INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (456);
            INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (789);
            SELECT * FROM test;
          EOF

Output:

